# Unit Test, Test Driven Development

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have a debate with my colleague regarding unit test and test driven development. The topic is below:

1) Writing a unit test before you write functional code does not constitute a Test Driven Development approach

I think Writing a unit test does constitute a test driven development, it is part of TDD.

2) a suite of unit tests is simply a by product of TDD.

A suite of unit test is NOT a by product of TDD.

What do you say?

Comment: 1. TDD is a superset of test-first. 2. You could say that given that you're using TDD to drive design vs just testing what you have. Subject to that, you could say that the design is the product, the tests are a bonus.

Answer (score 10):

1) Writing tests before you write functional code is *necessary* to do TDD, but does not by itself constitute TDD, at least according to the classic definition, where the important point is that making the tests pass is what drives the design (rather than some formal design document).

2) Again, the classic view says that the important point is that the design evolves from the tests, forcing it to be very modular. It is (or was) a novel concept that tests could (and should) influence the design, and perhaps often rejected or overlooked so that TDD proponents started to feel it needs to be stressed. But saying that the tests themselves are "just a byproduct" is IMO a counterproductive exaggeration.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on why unit test does not constitute a Test Driven Development?

Comment: @Pingpong: As I wrote: TDD means the design should be influenced by the test. If you complete your design before writing the tests, you're not doing classic TDD, even if you write them before starting to implement the design.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask it in another way, I use unit testing tool to carry out TDD. E.g. by using NUnit to write test code first in a Red, Green, Refactor cycle. Thus, it seems that unit test is part of the TDD.

Comment: @PingPong - A part, but not the whole: necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Writing unit tests prior to writing functional code is the whole point of TDD. So the suite of unit tests is not the by-product, it is the central tenent.

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)

> Test-driven development (TDD) is a software development process that relies on the repetition of a very short development cycle: first the developer writes a failing automated test case that defines a desired improvement or new function, then produces code to pass that test and finally refactors the new code to acceptable standards

Comment: agreed. If the test suite really were a by-product, then you would be able to take them away at any point, and continue your TDD. But you can't take them away, because they are required for the refactoring step. So any new features developed after taking away the tests would be test first, but not test driven.

Answer (score 4):

TDD is all about Red - Green - Refactor.

When you have code before test there is no Red and that is bad because you may have errors in your tests or test things other then you think you are testing and get Green from the start. You should be Red and then go to Green only after you add code that is tested by that test.

[image: Red-Green-Refactor]
<sub>(source:  [at reddevnews.com](http://reddevnews.com/%7E/media/ECG/visualstudiomagazine/Images/2007/11/listingsID_148_0711_rdn_tb%20gif.ashx))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what your tests do.

As far as I'm concerned TDD means that code classes, properties and methods are created due to the test being written for them first. In fact some development tools allow you to create code stubs directly from the test screens.

Writing a unit test for a method in a class that you've already created isn't TDD. Writing code that so that your test cases pass is.

TDD will give you far greater test coverage than standard unit testing. It will also focus your thoughts on what is wanted of the code, and although it may appear to take longer to produce a product by definition, it's more or less fully tested when built.

You will always end up with a suite of unit tests at the end.

However, a pragmatic approach must be taken as to how far you go with this as some areas are notoriously difficult to produce in a TDD environment e.g. WPF MVVM style views or web pages with javascript.